# SQL query with dynamic condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

My tables are in this [SQL Fiddle Link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a8918a/1)

The scenario: I have a `Customer` table(CustomerID,CustomerName) 
and `CustomerBills` table (customer id , bill date, value)

I also have a `Days` table (dayValue,Name)
 with values like (30, '1 Month') (60, '2 Months') (90, '3 Months').

I need a query get for each customer sum of bills based on days table

- Customer 1 - from 0 to 30 - sum(Amount)=1000
- Customer 2 - from 0 to 30 - sum(Amount)=1200
- Customer 1 - from 30 to 60 - sum(Amount)=800

Result sample:

[image: SQL Sample]

This is the report required

[image: Result]

Sample data

```sql
CREATE TABLE tblAge
    ([AgeDays] int, [AgeName] varchar(400))
;
    
INSERT INTO tblAge
    ([AgeDays], [AgeName])
VALUES
    (30, 'From 0 to 30 Days'),
    (90, '3 Months'),
    (180, '6 Months');
    
    CREATE TABLE tblCustomer
    ([ID] int, [Name] varchar(400))
;
    
INSERT INTO tblCustomer
    ([id], [Name])
VALUES
    (1, 'Cust 1'),
    (2, 'Cust 2'),
    (3, 'Cust 3');
    
    CREATE TABLE tblBills
    ([ID] int, [billDate] Datetime,[Amount] decimal,[CustID] int)
; 
INSERT INTO  tblBills
    ([ID] , [billDate] ,[Amount] ,[CustID] )
VALUES
    (1, '2020-12-01',200,1),
    (2, '2022-01-01',500,3),
    (3, '2021-04-05',300,2),
    (4, '2020-01-01',500,3),
    (5, '2021-01-01',500,1),
    (6, '2021-11-01',500,2),
    (7, '2021-08-01',500,3),
    (8, '2021-09-01',500,2),
    (9, '2021-07-01',500,1)
    ;
```

Comment: If the information is important include it in your question not in an off-site resource. The fiddle should compliment your question, not be required to visit for people to be able to answer it.

Comment: the fiddle is for table structure the data is variable - user entry

Comment: Yes, and if the table structure is important to your question, include it in the question. If it's not, then there is no need for the fiddle.

Comment: i did included it

Comment: Based on your sample data and today's date, I get `Cust 2  3 Months  500` `2  Cust 2  6 Months  500` `3  Cust 3  From 0 to 30 Days  500` `3  Cust 3  6 Months  500` so not sure how you get your results

Comment: no the result is for demonstration only sorry for that only to show the desired output - i wrote in the question i need the sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LAG` on the `tblAge` table to get what the previous age grouping is, then simply join based on that interval

```sql
SELECT
  c.ID,
  c.Name,
  SUM(b.Amount)
FROM tblCustomer c
JOIN tblBills b ON b.CustId = c.ID
JOIN (
    SELECT *,
      PrevDays = LAG(AgeDays, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY AgeDays)
    FROM tblAge
) a ON b.billDate >= DATEADD(day, a.AgeDays, GETDATE())
   AND b.billDate < DATEADD(day, a.PrevDays, GETDATE());
GROUP BY
  c.ID,
  c.Name;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a8918a/5)